# don't work Perl Operator `...` in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl

code:

```
$cmd = "dir";

$res = `$cmd`;
```

error msg:

```
Name "main::res" used only once: possible typo at C:/workspace/test_perl/main.pl line 2.
```

version is ActivePerl 5.16.3, eclipse luna.

OS is windows 7 32bit.

what is wrong?

I don't know... really.... help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is clear. You are only using `$res` once. You are putting data into the variable and then not using it. Your program will work the same way without that line of code. To remove that warning (and it's only a warning - not an error) just use that variable again somewhere in your code. Perhaps print the value or something like that.

If you don't want the output from `$cmd` then don't collect it. Perhaps use `system()` instead of backticks.

In a comment, you add:

> `<$a=1;>` or `<$a = scalar @array;>` is possible

Well, `$a` is special (as is `$b`). The fact that you use it in sort blocks means that it's immune from some of these checks. You probably shouldn't use `$a` or `$b` in your code (except in sort block) - it's a terrible name for a variable anyway.

Comment: Interestingly, `$a` does give this warning unless you're actually using it in a sort (5.10.1)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong. You've assigned a value to a variable then decided not to use it.

Perl is just warning you that you *may* have done something wrong, such as:

```
$res = `$cmd`;
if ($red eq 'ABC') {
    # Unreachable due to typo in condition
}
```

It is just a warning and you can choose to ignore it. In fact, you probably should ignore it and continue writing the rest of your code which I can only assume will use `$res` somehow and eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse only shows you, that the variable `res` is only used once. You assign a value, but you never use it.

Comment: why have to use it? <$a=1;> or <$a = scalar @array;> is possible... And this code is possible in unix server.

Comment: You don't have to use it. It's just a warning message, not an error message. It's warning you because when people calculate a value and then never use it, it's likely that this is because they've made a mistake somewhere in their logic (or made a typo with a variable name).